# Disk Utility Disk Verification

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, disk-utility, disk-volume

I ran the "Verify Disk" tool in disk utility on my main disk called Macintosh HD, and it came up with this log:

```
Verifying volume “Macintosh HD”
Checking storage systemChecking volume.
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group 4D3DFAA4-7124-4F3F-A19D-D06A1784AB17 spans 1 device
Logical Volume Group has a 16 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Load and verify Checkpoint Payload
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Load and verify Transaction Segment
Incorporate 1 newer non-checkpoint transactions
Load and verify Virtual Address Table
Load and verify Segment Usage Table
Load and verify Metadata Superblock
Load and verify Logical Volumes B-Trees
Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volumes
Load and verify E7324686-925A-48BF-8150-A982F1572F20
Load and verify 82E44F05-FEF5-49A9-B3C6-1911EE30BB49
Load and verify Freespace Summary
Load and verify Block Accounting
Load and verify Segment Cleaning
Newest transaction commit checkpoint is valid
The volume 4D3DFAA4-7124-4F3F-A19D-D06A1784AB17 appears to be OK.
Checking file systemPerforming live verification.
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file.
Checking multi-linked files.
Checking catalog hierarchy.
Checking extended attributes file.
Checking volume bitmap.
**Volume bitmap needs minor repair for orphaned blocks**
Checking volume information.
**Invalid volume free block count**
(It should be 85129597 instead of 81974060)
**The volume Macintosh HD was found corrupt and needs to be repaired.
Error: This disk needs to be repaired using the Recovery HD. Restart your computer,                 holding down the Command key and the R key until you see the Apple logo. When the Mac OS X Utilities window appears, choose Disk Utility.**
```

Do I need to follow the instructions at the bottom of the log? Is it necessary or can I forgo it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not absolutely required, but I'd say it's strongly recommended.  The type of volume corruption it reported isn't as serious as most other types, but my recommendation is the same: don't mess around, fix it *now*.

Answer (score 1):

## File system corruption

In an edge case (say, a hard disk drive with a **defective sector** used by a critical part of the file system structure (extents overflow B-tree, catalog B-tree, attributes B-tree and more)):

- a repair by `fsck_hfs` might do more harm than good, because drive-controlled reallocation of blocks may result in dataloss.

If you're lucky – **most people are** – then `fsck_hfs` without attention to media is the simplest and most appropriate course of action. So at the file system level (HFS Plus, in this case JHFS+) the [recommended action](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52901/8546) is almost indisputable.

## Storage system corruption

As Core Storage is closed source with too little information published by Apple, it's less clear what should be done about *newer non-checkpoint transactions*:

- [What's the significance of non-checkpoint transactions in Core Storage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88040/8546)

Hint: with Disk Utility, *apparently* OK is not always OK.